# Ability to render Active Record models in JSON with the inclusion and exclusion of fields/associations globally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want a way to set an ActiveRecord model to output only the fields I am letting it regardless of where it is accessed. I dont want to do this wherever an object of the model is accessed:

```
    @jobs = Job.all
    @jobs = @jobs.to_json(
          :include => {:job_status},
          :except  => [:created_at, :updated_at]
        )
```

I want to set this so that wherever the Job models object is rendered it will automatically include and exclude those fields/associations.

Comment: You may want to look at the activemodel-serializers gem which will give more control over the generated JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `as_json` on the `Job` class.

```
def as_json(options=nil)
  super(:include => {:job_status},
        :except  => [:created_at, :updated_at])
end
```

Comment: I think you meant to_json. I tried overriding both but it did not work.

Comment: No, I meant [as_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json). I'd be happy to help if you'd like to elaborate on how it didn't work.

Comment: I missed the options parameter! It works now. Btw why is the options parameter necessary?

Comment: The original `as_json` method makes `options` optional; I've updated my answer to reflect this original method signature, no longer requiring you to pass a value.

Comment: Is it possible to check what method is calling it? Lets say I have two methods "get_jobs_per_client" and "get_jobs_per_freelancer" I want to modify the JSON according to the method called. I tried passing it as an argument but I get the following error undefined method `merge' for "contact":String

Comment: It's funny, this is the 2nd or 3rd time in as many days I've linked to this gem on a question. If you're running into walls like this with JSON formatting for models, I **strongly** recommend taking a look at **[active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)**